# MySQL Inner Join With LIMIT to left table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this database query

```
SELECT *
FROM (`metadata` im)
INNER JOIN `content` ic ON `im`.`rev_id`  = `ic`.`rev_id`
WHERE `im`.`id` = '00039'
AND `current_revision` = 1
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 5, 5
```

The query limits the total rows in the result to 5. I want to limit the left table `metadata` to 5 without limiting the entire result-set.

How should I write the query?

Comment: what do you mean by limiting left table to 5?

Comment: @experimentX, 1 row in `metadata` may be related to `n` rows in `content`. I want to structure the query so that it returns `5n` rows, not 5 rows

Comment: @Shakti Singh thats what i am veering to, just thought there could be a more direct way

Comment: Can you add your table structure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you think about what you are trying to do, you're not really doing a select against `metadata`.

You need to sub query that first.

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((select * from metadata limit 5) im)
INNER JOIN `content` ic ON `im`.`rev_id`  = `ic`.`rev_id`
WHERE `im`.`id` = '00039'
AND `current_revision` = 1
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: This will get the first 5 rows of 'metadata' and then do further querying on that limited dataset.

Comment: @Ash - yes, that's what he asked.  "I want to limit the left table metadata to 5"

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible approach:

```
SET @serial=0;
SET @thisid=0;

SELECT 
   @serial := IF((@thisid != im.id), @serial + 1, @serial), 
   @thisid := im.id,
   * 
FROM (`metadata` im)
WHERE `im`.`id` = '00039'
AND `current_revision` = 1
AND @serial < 5
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

This isn't tested. Please let me know if you run into issue implementing this - and I can elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you mean `LEFT JOIN` try using `LEFT JOIN`  instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM (`metadata` im)
    INNER JOIN `content` ic ON `im`.`rev_id`  = `ic`.`rev_id`
    WHERE `im`.`id` = '00039'
    AND `current_revision` = 1
    ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
    LIMIT 5, 5
```

Comment: Tried that! Not what I want. A left join will incude any records in `left` table that dont have counterparts in the right table. An inner join will include only those records common to both

Comment: Though I don't recommend mine