# SQL limit SELECT but not JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, limit

I'm implementing pagination on my BD. My problem is when I want limit the SELECT statement but not the JOIN. Example, a product can got many prices:

```
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN price ON product.id == price.id_product
LIMIT 20
```

But I want to get 20 products with each one with their prices. How I can limit the statement SELECT, but not LEFT JOIN.

Example:

```
product             price.id  price.id_pruct  price.price
   1                   1            1               50
   2                   2            1               30
   3                   3            1               40
                       4            1               20
                       5            2               30

SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN price ON product.id == price.id_product
LIMIT 3
```

Return:

```
product  price.id id_prodcut price
1          1           1      50
1          2           1      30
1          3           1      40
```

But I Want

```
product  price.id id_prodcut price
1          1           1      50
1          2           1      30
1          3           1      40
1          4           1      20
2          5           2      30
3          .            .     .
```

Three products (limit 3)

Thanks. I hope you can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348705/how-to-limit-results-of-a-left-join

Comment: and see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126653/mysql-inner-join-with-limit-to-left-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a subquery to get the three first products (or whatever condition you choose) like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM product
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 3;
```

Once I have that, I can select everything from the price table as long as the id is in that subquery. You can do this using a join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM price p
JOIN(
   SELECT id
   FROM product
   ORDER BY id
   LIMIT 3) tmp ON tmp.id = p.product_id;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09df3/2) example using your sample data, and I also added a row that won't be returned so you can see that it works.

Comment: mmm I think it is the solution: changing the order of the SELECT.

Comment: I thought there was some statement or combination of brackets to solve the problem

Comment: @jlmg5564 I don't understand. The order of the columns as they are written in the select statement is irrelevant, it only matters for display purposes. And this is a statement to solve the problem, the answer contains a link to an example to show that it worked. If that is not what you want, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english @McAdam331 Your solution is right. And thanks for the example in SQL Fiddle. I was thinking out loud: "select prices and join with products, not select product and join with their prices"

Comment: @jlmg5564 not a problem, lost in translation haha. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Modify your query to limit the number of product rows before joining it to the price table.  This means we want to to join the results of a query to a table, or in other words, we write a query containing a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM product
    ORDER BY id_product
    LIMIT 3
) p
LEFT JOIN price ON p.id = price.id_product
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect the reason is because code only answers are often discouraged on StackOverflow. Please edit to explain your answer. In addition,  it would be a good idea to order your subquery so you know which three results you are getting, and the comparison operator should have one equal sign.