# get data from sqlite limited on inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sqflite

I want to get rooms limited to 20 with last message only order by lastMessage.created_at DESC

message table

```
     create table tb_message (
            message_id varchar(50) primary key  ,
            room_id varchar(50) not null,
            message_type text not null,
            message text not null,
            sender_id varchar(50) not null,
            recipient_id varchar(50) not null,
            reply_id varchar(50) default null ,
            created_at BIGINT ,
            status integer ,
            constraint tb_message_chat_id_fk foreign key (room_id) references tb_room (room_id),
            constraint tb_message_sender_user_fk foreign key (sender_id) references tb_user (user_id),
            constraint tb_message_recipient_user_fk foreign key (recipient_id) references tb_user (user_id))
```

rooms table

```
          create table tb_room (
            room_id  varchar(50) primary key ,
            group_id varchar(50),
            room_type text ,
            owner_id varchar(50) not null ,
            is_muted integer default 0,
             constraint tb_chat_user_id_fk foreign key (owner_id) references tb_user (user_id))
```

user table

```
      create table tb_user (
            user_id varchar(50) primary key ,
            user_name text not null,
            online_status integer )
```

my query is

```
      SELECT *
      FROM  (select * from tb_room limit 20) as room
      
      INNER JOIN tb_message 
        ON room.room_id = (select room_id from tb_message   limit 1)  
        
      INNER JOIN tb_user
        ON tb_user.user_id = room.owner_id
      ORDER BY tb_message.created_at DESC
```

it return all room with its all messages

Comment: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` usually doesn't make sense.

Comment: see this ans please https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126818/9294077

Comment: the condition in the `ON` clause needs to relate the two tables being joined. A subquery in the `ON` clause is not correct.

Comment: That answer makes the same mistake. Unless you don't care which room you select.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. Do you want the last message for 20 rooms, or the last 20 messages for each room?

Comment: Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sqlite?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x or SQLite you should be able to do it with a window function.

Comment: I need 20 rooms with 1 message for each room, not all messages only one  last message for each room I use Sqlite